# "Footprint" of the Park Tool PCS 9 stand

Tags: tools, repair-stand

I am trying to workout whether the [park tool PCS 9 workstand](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/se/en/park-tool-home-mechanic-repair-stand-pcs9/rp-prod5787) would fit in my bath tub (it's the only place I can clean my bike). To do so I need to know how big the footprint of the stand is.

Could someone measure theirs for me?

Approximately it's the distances in this image along the red lines...

[image]

Comment: The only place you can clean your bike is the tub?  Take a bucket of water to the parking lot is not an option?  Why would you get a $100+ stand wet?  Why do you need your bike on a stand to clean it?

Comment: There are, of course, other places I *can* go to wash my bike, like the car park (I could even just tie it to a rope and throw it in the river, but that would be quite inconvenient). I live on the third floor of my building with no elevator and no outside tap to rinse with = lots of walking up and down stairs and having to leave my bike outside unattended. I'm planning to put the stand in the bath because it makes it easier to get the bike in to a workable position. Besides, I could do with a work stand anyway.

Comment: I can measure it this evening. But you would need one heck of a fancy bath tub to fit the stand in.

Comment: I have a Nashbar stand (which is likely dimensioned the same way as the park tool one), and theres no way it would fit in a standard US bathtub.

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised that your bike fits lengthwise in the tub.  From a quick look on the internet, a standard road bike is roughly 68 inches, which is about as long as I am tall, and there's no way I can completely lie down, stretched out in the bath.  I guess you can make it a bit shorter by turning the handlebars, but it still seems like it would be a tight fit.

Comment: I have that stand and a standard bathtub, no way it would fit.

Comment: @kibble yeah I normally pop the front wheel off - the thinking with the stand was I could rotate it (as if the bike is pointing upwards sort of)

Comment: I've go a pcs9 and a bigger than standard bathtub and it won't fit in!!

Comment: If you live in a 3rd floor apartment the PCS9 isin't suited. It's cumbersome and doesn't fold down much. I have a 2 car garage with only a treadmill and 4 bikes in it and the stand still seems to large!

Comment: I've been using that Park stand at a place where I rehab bikes for Christmas Anonymous.  My impression (can't look at the stand until tomorrow) is that it would not fit in a standard bathtub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, these are all "back of the envelope" estimates... The actual measurements will vary but it will give you an idea. You should maybe send an email to Park or stop by your LBS if they carry these stands confirm the measurements and check my math.

**Assumption 1- Leg Length**

From the park tool site link it says that the whole stand folds to 41". If you watch the video you see that when folded the head and mount stick up above the legs. It's likely more than 5 inches, but I estimated that if you account for that excess the legs are about 36" long.

**Assumption 2 - Right Angles**

My next assumption is that the legs open at a 90-degree angle. Then we can do some high school math.

**Do the Math!**

If both legs are 36" and the angle is 90-degrees, then then length of "b" in you diagram can be figured with the Pythagorean Theorem, 36^2 + 36^2 = b^2. My math tells me that "b" equals roughly 51".

If you put the pointy end against one side of the tub and legs against the other side, you then create the smaller triangles formed by the legs, the vertex "a" and 1/2 of "b". Again, using the same formula you have 36^2 + a^2 = 25.5^2. That equals roughly 26".

**Conclusion**

So, based on those assumptions (right angles and 36" legs), if your tub is wider at the interior base than 26" (66 cm) then the stand should fit.

*Edit:* If the length of the legs is about 25" as indicated in a comment that has since been deleted, then the length of "a" in your diagram is about 17.5" (44.5 cm).

Comment: For the real math geeks, you can use geometry to skip the second set of calculations. If you have a isosceles right triangle A-A-H and you bisect the hypotenuse, the A side become the hypotenuse of the two smaller right triangles and the length of both smaller sides is equal to 1/2 H.

Answer (score 11):

From the Park Tool support site, [here](http://www.parktool.com/product/home-mechanic-repair-stand-pcs-9):

> Base when open forms a triangle of 36” (92 cm) x  36” (92 cm)x 45”
>   (115 cm)

Answer (score 10):

I measured my PCS9 at:

- a) 70 cm (27.5")
- b) 115 cm (45")